# Priority levels of SCHED_OTHER scheduling policy

Tags: c, scheduler, scheduling

I'm looking for the range of the priority levels of the SHCED_OTHER scheduling policy, but in the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html) it seems that this information is not reported.
Maybe is the only priority level 0?

Comment: Well, the documentation you linked clearly states that `sched_priority` is not used for such processes/threads and must be specified as 0. If you need priority-based scheduling, you have to install a real-time kernel and then use `SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_real_time/7/html/reference_guide/chap-priorities_and_policies) I found the answer:

SCHED_OTHER or SCHED_NORMAL is the default scheduling policy for Linux threads. It has a dynamic priority that is changed by the system based on the characteristics of the thread. Another thing that effects the priority of SCHED_OTHER threads is their nice value. The nice value is a number between -20 (highest priority) and 19 (lowest priority). By default, SCHED_OTHER threads have a nice value of 0. Adjusting the nice value will change the way the thread is handled.